# Haskell Iterating through Loop with ability to look back

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I am learning Haskell currently and running into a problem where I am trying iterate through a list but I need the ability to return to the start of the list. For instance, if my list of tuples is is:

`[(1,5), (4,3), (5,6), (1,7), (7,9), (3,11)]`

I need to go from 1 to 4 to 5... I am doing this currently by recursively calling my function on the tail of the list. This works as it should but here is the problem:

I am matching the numbers to another list of tuples. So for instance, my second list would be something like

`[(6,10)]`

So Neither 1 or 5 match 6 or 10, neither 4 or 3 match 6 or 10 but the 6 from `(5,6)` matches so I would add it to the front. and now I need to start back at the front of the list. The problem is the way I am iterating, calling the function by calling the tail means I can't see the `(1,5), (4,3)` I have been struggling to conceptually solve this problem for the better half of a week. I know how to the whole `(head list) : function (tail list)` but since my return is the new list of matched pairs I can't quite get that to work.

Not sure if that makes sense but in a nutshell after adding the `(5,6)` to the list I get the result of `[(5,6),(6,10)]` which is good but when I want to now start checking again it starts with `(1,7)` instead of `(1,5)` which would match now.

My code is in pieces right now in the middle of a solution so it would be a giant mess to show. Plus I am really just wanting help trying to conceptualize what I have to do.

**EDIT**

Ok to clear up some confusion, lets say I have two lists:

`list1: [(8,7),(1,5),(8,9),(4,3),(5,6),(1,7),(11,9)]
 list2: [(6,10),(10,12)]`

I have a function that takes both lists and will return the updated list2. List1 compares the characters in it's tuples with the characters at the front and rear of list2's tuples (I don't want to insert into between as they are linked `...,10)<-->(10,...`). So starting off, `(8,7)` does not match to either the `6` or `12` so I move on. Now when I move on I am calling back my function and passing it the tail of list1.

for instance:
`master list1 list2 
      | comparisons.... = master (tail list1) (addToList list2)
      . 
      .
      .
      | otherwise = master (tail list1) list2`

I am not writing out all the comparisons to save space but they all work fine and it goes through the list as it should except for one part. Back to the list, I now have `(1,5)` which against doesn't match so I pass off the tail and get to `(8,9)`, again nothing so I progress, `(4,3)` doesn't match so I get to `(5,6)` which does match, I can flip it and add it to the front to make `[(5,6),(6,10),(10,12)]` and now I would remove `(5,6)` from list1 as I already added it to list2.  The problem is now I Would again pass the tail and be on `(1,7)` and then `(11,9)` which would then end the program because we are at the end of the list.

My desired output would be `[(11,9),(9,8),(8,7),(7,1),(1,5),(5,6),(6,10),(10,12)]` instead of `[(5,6),(6,10),(10,12)]`

Again, code isn't really going to help me I just want someone to offer up a different way to think of it. This is my first time touching a functional language and to say I am confused at parts is an understatement.

Comment: Can you give example input/output? for example `f [(1,5), (4,3), (5,6), (1,7), (7,9), (3,11)] [(6, 10)] = ...?`

Comment: So expected would be: [(1,5),(5,6)(6,10)] whereas my output is [(5,6)(6,10)]  because my function continues down the tail and loses focus on the old head's

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you'd get anything but an infinite list `(1, 5)` matches both the `1` and the `5` -- so what's causing the base case?

Comment: I also don't understand the problem description. You say that you need to return to the start of the list, but this is perhaps because you have not aggregated your input in such a way that it's immediately accessible in the way that you need it to be. You say "I need to go from 1 to 4 to 5", but what does that mean? What happens when you "go" to 4? These seem to be the 1st part of the tuples; what is the significance of the 2nd part? Try and rephrase your problem description so it describes the problem and not your solution so far. (You can describe this separately of course.)

Comment: I added an edit which hopefully helps clear somethings up, sorry guys for not providing enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're learning Haskell, I guess you probably want to solve this problem yourself, so let me show you how might solve a simpler variation.  Let's say we have a list of words, and we want to build a new list of words where, for each adjacent pair, the last letter of the first word in the pair matches the first letter of the last word.  However, we'll **only** add words to the end of our list (unlike your example where you can add pairs to the beginning or end, or maybe even somewhere in the middle -- it wasn't clear from your description).

So, if we start with a list of words:

```
["cat","bat","cow","war","rot","tar"]
```

and a "seed" list:

```
["tub"]
```

then we'd like:

```
link ["cat","bat","cow","war","rot","tar"] ["tub"]
```

to give:

```
["tub","bat","tar","rot"]
```

Here, starting with the list `["tub"]`, we've found the first word that *starts* with a "b", so we can add it to the end to get `["tub","bat"]`, then we search for the remaining first word that starts with "t" to get `["tub","bat","tar"]`, and then we search for the first remaining word that starts with "r" to get `["tub","bat","tar","rot"]`, and then the program ends because there are no remaining words that start with "t".

Our first try (which I think is similar to your algorithm above) might be:

```
link :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
link (wrd:wrds) chain
  | lastLetter == head wrd = link wrds (chain ++ [wrd])
  | otherwise              = link wrds chain
  where lastLetter = last (last chain)
link [] chain = chain
```

Unfortunately, this gives the wrong answer:

```
> link ["cat","bat","cow","war","rot","tar"] ["tub"]
["tub","bat","tar"]
>
```

It misses `"rot"` because it only processes the tail of the list of words after adding `"tar"`, and there are no more words left.  You need it to go back to the beginning of the list, and this is where you're stuck.

The problem is that, when you get the first successful match on `"bat"`, the recursive call is:

```
link wrds (chain ++ [wrd])
=
link ["cow","war","rot","tar"] (["tub"] ++ ["bat"])
```

instead of:

```
link wrds (chain ++ [wrd])
=
link ["cat","cow","war","rot","tar"] (["tub"] ++ ["bat"])
```

You somehow need to include the list of unmatched words you've already processed (namely `["cat"]`) as well as the tail of the list of words (starting with `"cow"`).

In Haskell, if you need some information (like the "list of unmatched words you've already processed), you usually pass it along as an extra parameter.  So, let's rewrite `link` to take that extra list:

```
link' :: [String] -> [String] -> [String] -> [String]
link' unmatched (wrd:wrds) chain = ...
```

with the idea that the initial list of unmatched words will be empty:

```
> link' [] ["cat","bat","cow","war","rot","tar"] ["tub"]
```

Now, let's figure out the definition of `link'`.  We'll start with the easiest case, the "otherwise" case, where we did *not* match on the current `wrd`.  In this case, we add `wrd` to the list of unmatched words and continue looking in the rest of the `wrds`:

```
... | otherwise = link' (unmatched ++ [wrd]) wrds chain
```

On the other hand, if we *do* match, we want to add the word to the chain:

```
... | lastLetter == head wrd = link' ?? ?? (chain ++ [wrd])
```

but what should the first two arguments be?  Well, we want to start fresh, looking through all the words in the list except the `wrd` we matched.  That is, we want to look through all the `unmatched` words, plus the rest of the `wrds`, so we want:

```
... | lastLetter == head wrd = link' ?? (unmatched ++ wrds) (chain ++ [wrd])
```

What about the first argument for this call?  Well, we're starting fresh, so there aren't any unmatched words -- the unmatched list should be empty:

```
... | lastLetter == head wrd = link' [] (unmatched ++ wrds) (chain ++ [wrd])
```

This gives the complete, updated definition:

```
link' :: [String] -> [String] -> [String] -> [String]
link' unmatched (wrd:wrds) chain
  | lastLetter == head wrd = link' [] (unmatched ++ wrds) (chain ++ [wrd])
  | otherwise              = link' (unmatched ++ [wrd]) wrds chain
  where lastLetter = last (last chain)
```

What about the terminating case:

```
link' unmatched [] chain = ???
```

This is perhaps a little trickier.  However, remember that, if we ever *match* a word, we jump back to the beginning with:

```
link' [] (unmatched ++ wrds) (chain ++ [wrd])
```

If there's at least one word left (i.e., if `(unmatched ++ wrds)` is non-empty), we'll keep going with a non-terminating case.  The only way we could get to the terminating case would be if (1) we matched the last available word and jumped back to the "beginning" with an empty word list, or (2) we got to the end of the word list without a match.  In *either* case, the chain is complete -- in case (1), all words in the word list have been successfully added to the chain; in case (2), the word list is non-empty, but none of the words can be successfully added.  So, in *either* case, we want to stop and return the chain, and the terminating case is:

```
link' unmatched [] chain = chain
```

When you use an "extra" parameter like this, it's common to wrap things up in a helper function, so the final revised definition of `link` would look something like this:

```
link :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
link wrds chain = link' [] wrds chain
  where
    link' unmatched (wrd:wrds) chain
      | lastLetter == head wrd = link' [] (unmatched ++ wrds) (chain ++ [wrd])
      | otherwise              = link' (unmatched ++ [wrd]) wrds chain
      where lastLetter = last (last chain)
    link' unmatched [] chain = chain
```

This now gives the right answer:

```
> link ["cat","bat","cow","war","rot","tar"] ["tub"]
["tub","bat","tar","rot"]
>
```

Comment: After reading over this once it seems to be extremely helpful. Let me do some digging and I'll comment back any questions. But this is exactly what I was talking about. Thank you for writing in an easy to understand manner as well.